# Image file is not being located

Tags: php, wordpress, image

**Hi , I have placed in my php to get the image file from the folder, but it is giving me a error in the source saying**

> Warning: Division by zero in

**My code is :** 
`<img src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory') /imgs/Logo.png;?>" alt="Logo" class="logo">`

**It was working for me last week , i forget what I have changed but now can not fix this , can anyone please help?**

Comment: Please post all the relevant code, it seems you have left some stuff out.

Answer (score 2):

```
<img src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/imgs/Logo.png';?>" alt="Logo" class="logo">
```

Comment: The difference in our answers' shows the 2 types of PHP developers. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<img src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory');?>/imgs/Logo.png" alt="Logo" class="logo">
```

Comment: Brilliant thank you , such a small mistake but Ill defo have to keep this in mind thank you